# Change width of UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

i'm having a hamburger menu where i'm showing a viewController with a tableView. The problem is that i've added a UISearchBar to the titleView and as u can see some the searchBar is hiding. Is there a way i' can make the navigationBar smaller or the searchBar so it will fit ?

[image]

Comment: How do you know any of the search bar is "hiding"? You have something covering part of your view. Take that stuff out of the way so you can see where the search bar really is.

Comment: What i want is to make the searchBar smaller such that it fits

Comment: It does fit. It fits the navigation bar. You are the one who is covering it.

Comment: If you don't want it to fit the whole navigation bar, don't make it the `titleView`. Make it the `leftBarButtonItem` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth-30, 44))
    searchBar?.delegate = self
    searchBar?.showsCancelButton = false

    var textField = searchBar?.valueForKey("searchField") as UITextField
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#414e5c")
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Never
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    textField.clipsToBounds = true


    searchBar?.placeholder = "Søg efter produkter"
    searchBar?.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, 0), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search)



    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    searchController = UISearchDisplayController()
    searchController?.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchResultsDelegate = self
    var buttonSearchBar:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar!)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonSearchBar
```